# Determine the interior of the set $(-1)^n+1/n$ for $n$ positive integer

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification, metric-spaces

$\newcommand{\int}{\operatorname{int}}\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$
Consider the metric space $(\mathbb{R},d)$, with $d(x,y)=|x-y|$. Let $A=\left\{(-1)^n+\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{Z}_+\right\}$. I need to find the interior set, $\int{(A)}$, of $A$ and show that it is indeed the interior. Where $x\in\int{(A})$ iff there is an $\varepsilon>0$ such that the open ball $B(x,\varepsilon)\subseteq A$.

My candidate for the interior is the set $\varnothing$. Here's my proof attempt.

*Proof.* Suppose $\int{(A)}\ne\varnothing$, thus we can choose an $x\in\int{(A)}$. Therefore, there is an $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B(x,\varepsilon)=(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\subseteq A$.

Note that $A\subset\mathbb{Q}$, for proving this let $a\in A$, then $a=(-1)^n+1/n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$. If $n$ is odd $a=-1+1/n=(1-n)/n$, and if $n$ is even $a=1+1/n=(n+1)/n$ for some $m\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, in all cases we see that $a\in\mathbb{Q}$, thus $A\subset\mathbb{Q}$.

Now, since $x-\varepsilon<x+\varepsilon$, by the theorem of the density of irrational numbers in the real numbers, we can choose an irrational $p\in\mathbb{R-Q}$ such that $x-\varepsilon<p<x+\varepsilon$, hence $p\in(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\subseteq A\subset\mathbb{Q}$, which is a contradiction. Then $\int{(A)}=\varnothing$.

Is this proof right? Would you have any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: No countable set can have interior points (since open intervals are uncountable).

Comment: Also, $\mathrm{int}(A)\subseteq\mathrm{int}(\Bbb Q)=\Bbb R\setminus\bar{\Bbb Q}=\emptyset$